# "date" command in bash, the results are displayed in Japanese language

Tags: linux, bash, debian, xubuntu

I have the same problem on two of my Linux boxes (xubuntu, debian). When I use the "date" command in bash, the results are displayed in Japanese language.

2014年  9月  2日 火曜日 02:48:48 UTC

I am located in Japan and under the Japanese time zone, but I would like my working environment, including the output of the date command, to be in English.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not determined by the timezone, but rather by **locale** settings.

I'm not sure if Xfce has an UI for specifying system locale in a detailed enough manner. But at the low level, there are several environment variables, which you can see by typing `locale`. The main one is `$LANG`, which sets the general system locale, and for specific areas there are separate `$LC_*` variables – e.g. `$LC_MESSAGES` for the translations used by programs, and `$LC_TIME` for the date/time formats.

If you simply want *everything* to be in English, then the configuration is simple – select an English locale in your Xfce settings. (Typically "United States" aka en_US.UTF-8, though I use en_DK.UTF-8 for LC_TIME myself, as it gives ISO 8601 dates.) **This will not affect time zones at all.**

If you want *specific* settings for English and others for Japanese, you might have to manually "export" the specific variables in your `~/.profile` or `/etc/default/locale` or ... wherever Ubuntu puts it. For example:

```
LANG="en_US.utf-8"
LC_COLLATE="lt_LT.utf-8"
LC_TIME="en_DK.utf-8"
```

(In `~/.profile`, using `export LANG=...` is necessary.)

---

Another thing to note that if you switch between two `*.utf-8` locales, it will *not* affect the character sets either – *any* UTF-8 locale still uses Unicode, so Japanese text will still work with `en_US.utf-8`. (Not to be confused with the old `en_US` which uses legacy ISO 8859.)

Comment: thank you grawity, yes I simply want *everything* to be in English. How can I change my "Xfce settings"? I.e. I don't know in which file I can change that.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't look like Xfce even has settings for this, so try `/etc/default/locale`.